# Programmatically insert UIScrollView within UIStackView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am wondering if it is possible to put a `UIScrollView` within a `UIStackView` that is in another main `UIStackView`.  I perform a google and stackview search for this answer, but all that was return was the inverse of my question.

[image]

Comment: Yes you can. Just add the scroll view as an arranged view of the stack view in question, and add the appropriate constraints.

Comment: Have you tried?  I don't know why you couldn't, although whether or not it works the way you want is unknown.  It seems like something you could easily test in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved due to the advice of both Rob and Jason.